# JavaScript Object notation type confusion

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am somehow confused about JS object notations. What I know is: There are 2 types of object notations.

```
var myObj = new Object(); // Object constructor notation
var myObj = {...} // Object literal notation
```

Object literal is the latest standard and most people use it now a days.

But I have found some people using following notation.

```
var vm = this;
vm.value = ...;
```

Can someone explain me about the third type and can tell me, is it literal or constructor.

Thanks.

Comment: `console.log(this)`

Comment: The first two are syntax used to create a new object. The last is just working with an existing object.

Comment: Hi, If there is no object created before this, then its using default object???

Comment: The last one depends on the context, i.e. where that piece of code is placed.

Comment: If it isn't in a function this refers to the window object. When you call vm = this you copy all the properties of the window object to vm.

Comment: hmm, thanks @David Now I am getting clear picture

Comment: @David `vm` will then point to the window object. There is no copying involved.

Comment: Oh right so if I overwrite vm.innerWidth to something else I will be changing that value for the window object too.